# ABB OPC server DA 2.0 run time error..no more thread can be created

Tags: multithreading, c#-4.0, opc

first time asking questions here.

So I am using a the OPC server that comes with Freelance 2013 to pull some data from the DCS system for my application. In my application I am using the c# with OPCAutomation.DLL , and I create a seperate thread every second to call SyncRead on the server to get the data.

However, what i foud out is that after running for about 3 hours or so, the server will always crash with a C++ run time error, and within my c# application I got a interop.COMexception , syaying "No more thread can be created"

So I was wondering if someone could please point out why is this happening?

My suspicion is that since my timercallback call SyncRead every second using a different thread, those threads get hang up on the server and never get released. 
If this is the case, what should i do to work around this?
Thanks

Tags
OPC server, thread,c#

Comment: It is much more likely that this means that *you* have created too many threads in your client application. Errors between from the OPC server are passed by means of HRESULT codes, and to my knowledge there is no code for this kind of message. Both the OPC Server and the OPC client will have to go to bigger lengths to be able to pass through messages associated with custom error codes - either using IErrorInfo, or the OPC way, i.e. IOPCCommon::GetErrorString.

Comment: @ZbynekZ thank you for ur reply..thats what i am suspecting as well...but the piculiar thing is that the OPC server supplied by ABB cashed as well with a c++ run time error, and the error i am getting is indeed a interop.COMexception...which leads to speculate it is the COM object i am using(the OPC server) that is cauing the error

Comment: The original question did not mention COMException; my comment would have been different if it did. Are you waiting for the previous sync read to finish, before you issue a new one? If you are not, then you might indeed be causing the server to create many threads internally - depending on how it is implemented.

Comment: @ZbynekZ Again thank you for your reply. I am not waiting for the previous SyncRead to finish before I issue the next read, and I think what you said might actually be the reason why. I will drop my reading frequency to test it out. Hopefully my mistake will help others with the same problem.